# Is there a training example of using Tensorflow C++ API?

Tags: tensorflow

To be clear, I do not want to load a pretrained model in C++. I want to do the training in C++ and then use the model.

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to do training using the C++ API for a few days now, as far as I've found there is no full example to be found using the 1.2 release. I've yet to give up, if I do manage to make a working example (I'm trying to recognize digits from MNIST) I will post it here. In 1.2, the way sessions are run was changed and the documentation is very scarce.

If you're willing to use an older version of the C++ API, this example in the source code should suffice:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/tutorials/example_trainer.cc.

Comment: I've abandoned my attempts at training the model in C++ for the time being, I will return to it with the next release. Just thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 2):

The following side offers a good example for training an model from scratch, unfortunatly there is no way for saving the trained example. He also explaines the code.
I've been using this one: 
https://matrices.io/training-a-deep-neural-network-using-only-tensorflow-c/
(It is the first example for training a tensorflow-NN in c++)

Some basic tests are also done in my repository:
https://github.com/PinkySan/TensorflowHandlingTests

```
  Scope scope = Scope::NewRootScope();

  auto x = Placeholder(scope, DT_FLOAT);
  auto y = Placeholder(scope, DT_FLOAT);

  // weights init
  auto w1 = Variable(scope, {3, 3}, DT_FLOAT);
  auto assign_w1 = Assign(scope, w1, RandomNormal(scope, {3, 3}, DT_FLOAT));

  auto w2 = Variable(scope, {3, 2}, DT_FLOAT);
  auto assign_w2 = Assign(scope, w2, RandomNormal(scope, {3, 2}, DT_FLOAT));

  auto w3 = Variable(scope, {2, 1}, DT_FLOAT);
  auto assign_w3 = Assign(scope, w3, RandomNormal(scope, {2, 1}, DT_FLOAT));

  // bias init
  auto b1 = Variable(scope, {1, 3}, DT_FLOAT);
  auto assign_b1 = Assign(scope, b1, RandomNormal(scope, {1, 3}, DT_FLOAT));

  auto b2 = Variable(scope, {1, 2}, DT_FLOAT);
  auto assign_b2 = Assign(scope, b2, RandomNormal(scope, {1, 2}, DT_FLOAT));

  auto b3 = Variable(scope, {1, 1}, DT_FLOAT);
  auto assign_b3 = Assign(scope, b3, RandomNormal(scope, {1, 1}, DT_FLOAT));

  // layers
  auto layer_1 = Tanh(scope, Tanh(scope, Add(scope, MatMul(scope, x, w1), b1)));
  auto layer_2 = Tanh(scope, Add(scope, MatMul(scope, layer_1, w2), b2));
  auto layer_3 = Tanh(scope, Add(scope, MatMul(scope, layer_2, w3), b3));

  // regularization
  auto regularization = AddN(scope,
                             initializer_list<Input>{L2Loss(scope, w1),
                                                     L2Loss(scope, w2),
                                                     L2Loss(scope, w3)});

  // loss calculation
  auto loss = Add(scope,
                  ReduceMean(scope, Square(scope, Sub(scope, layer_3, y)), {0, 1}),
                  Mul(scope, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), regularization));

  // add the gradients operations to the graph
  std::vector<Output> grad_outputs;
  TF_CHECK_OK(AddSymbolicGradients(scope, {loss}, {w1, w2, w3, b1, b2, b3}, &grad_outputs));

  // update the weights and bias using gradient descent
  auto apply_w1 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, w1, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), {grad_outputs[0]});
  auto apply_w2 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, w2, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), {grad_outputs[1]});
  auto apply_w3 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, w3, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), {grad_outputs[2]});
  auto apply_b1 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, b1, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), {grad_outputs[3]});
  auto apply_b2 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, b2, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), {grad_outputs[4]});
  auto apply_b3 = ApplyGradientDescent(scope, b3, Cast(scope, 0.01,  DT_FLOAT), {grad_outputs[5]});

  ClientSession session(scope);
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;

  // init the weights and biases by running the assigns nodes once
  TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({assign_w1, assign_w2, assign_w3, assign_b1, assign_b2, assign_b3}, nullptr));

  // training steps
  for (int i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
    if (i % 100 == 0) {
      TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({{x, x_data}, {y, y_data}}, {loss}, &outputs));
      std::cout << "Loss after " << i << " steps " << outputs[0].scalar<float>() << std::endl;
    }
    // nullptr because the output from the run is useless
    TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({{x, x_data}, {y, y_data}}, {apply_w1, apply_w2, apply_w3, apply_b1, apply_b2, apply_b3}, nullptr));
  }
```

Comment: He askes for an example of training with c++. I can copy the code from the first link and at it into my answer, but the code is pretty long. In my opinion that doesn't make sense and it worsens the view of the ticket

Answer (score -1):

I think the best strategy to train the model in Python, save it and then load the frozen model in C++. I written instructions written how to freeze a checkpoint in Tensorflow (TFLearn) and load this model for inference with the C/C++ API:

https://github.com/kecsap/tensorflow_cpp_packaging/blob/master/README.md#save-a-checkpoint-in-python-tflearn

I would be too long to copy paste the instructions here.